# Можно сказать "строимые дома"?

Tags: морфология

В парадигме Зализняка эта форма указана, но реально "строимый" используется крайне редко, да и то в основном в старых текстах, например:

В июне 1716 года Петр... велел устроить в разных селах...хоромы, с приказною избою и тюрьмою на деньги, собранные с крестьян, на строимый двор. [Н. И. Костомаров (1862-1875)]

Но вот в Интернете даже обсуждается вопрос: "Строимый" или "строемый" ― как правильно пишется слово?

http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2901191-stroimyj-ili-stroemyj-kak-pravilno-pishetsja-slovo.html

В то же время орфографическая программа подчеркивает слово. Что с ним не так? Может быть, эта форма устарела?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**А.** Вот что утверждает Ю. Князев ([Грамматическая семантика. Русский язык в типологической перспективе](https://books.google.ee/books?id=hWjMAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA492&lpg=PA492&dq=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=nsVJuxv9Au&sig=msjQa8hLlwSYhIfuUZt3zpi7z2o&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwigj6vJhrjeAhUPesAKHUNVDlIQ6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9&f=false)):
Возможности образования и употребления таких причастий сокращаются на протяжении долгого времени: вышли из употребления встречавшиеся ранее формы типа *учимый, держимый или строимый...*

**Б.** Вот что пишет А. Пешковский в книге [Русский синтаксис в научном освещении](https://books.google.ee/books?id=nSZqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=itt4fkBOcY&sig=E6cZGgjv02nAJjh7b_WEKs0C6Vk&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6vtibhbjeAhVFiCwKHfj9BgoQ6AEwBnoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE&f=false):
И вот как раз форма на ***-мый*** от глагола *строить* (*строимый*) принадлежит к редко употребляющимся, и потому мы не только м о ж е м сказать *дом, **строящийся** этим архитектором*, но, пожалуй (даже и н а в е р н о е), так скажем, а не скажем *дом, **строимый** этим архитектором.*

**В.** Л. Р. Бакирова, к. филол. н., О. С. Тарасенко, к. филол. н. ([Изучение причастия на занятиях по русскому языку как иностранному](http://scjournal.ru/articles/issn_1997-2911_2017_12-2_55.pdf)):
*Упражнение 7. Сравните следующие предложения и объясните разницу их употребления.*
2. Дом, который строят рабочие, будет готов в этом году. – Дом, строимый рабочими, будет готов в этом году.

*Кровь пошла не скоро и не грея,

Нервы снова вызвали тоску:

Если электричество стареет,

Сколько в юности моей секунд?*

*Сколько времени еще осталось

Мне брести до станции Усталость?

**В строимый огромный дом**

Я боюсь явиться стариком.*
М. Светлов (1922)

Три мнения — выбирайте любое.
Я бы все-таки остановилась на том, что причастие правильное (см. также [Подготовка к ЕГЭ...](https://books.google.ee/books?id=LREsDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=es2W3MyQdN&sig=7htzQiHCXwYD26pjDIckRbnMrr4&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiknJ3ehLjeAhUDBywKHU-HBkYQ6AEwBnoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE&f=false) и [3.8.1.4. Образование причастий](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/689-381_ponyatie_o_prichastii_razryady_prichastii_obrazovanie_prichastii.html)), но употребляемое нечасто. Словосочетание *строимый дом* используется и сегодня, даже приводится в качестве примера в учебниках.

Comment: Так вы употребляете  выражение "строимые дома"? А я почему-то была уверена, что этой формы  в современном языке нет. Дело в том, что причастные формы этого вида имеют фонетические ограничения, их образование  не является регулярным. В частности, причастия не образуют некоторые переходные глаголы несовершенного вида: брать, ждать, писать, мазать, колоть, лить, пить, шить, мыть, рыть, мять.  Я решила, что глагол строить тоже попал под эти ограничения. Возможно,  форма "строимый" кажется нам или наблагозвучной, или плохо различимой в речи.

Comment: А вот то, что примеры даются в учебнике, меня несколько настораживает.  Есть в этом какая-то механическая формальность: слово уже уйдет из языка, но в учебниках все равно будет разбираться.

Comment: Дискомфортное какое-то слово, несовременное, невоспринимаемое. Я бы его не использовала и заменила возможными синонимами: воздвигаемый, сооружаемый, создаваемый... И я тоже удивлена **такому** академическому подходу.

Comment: Приведу в комментарии цитату из первого тома "Русской грамматики" Н.Ю. Шведовой: *У большинства глаголов кл. X образование страдат. причастий наст. вр. затруднено; такие причастия отмечаются преимущественно в книжной **архаизирующей** речи: грабимый, помнимый, хоронимый. Лишь некоторые из таких причастий лишены окраски книжности и высокости: ...* (здесь среди прочих примеров приводится слово **строимый**).

Comment: Вопрос-то, собственно, звучит так: _Можно сказать “строимые дома”?_ Да, так говорить можно. Уж насколько это воспринимаемо в том или ином контексте - это уже другой вопрос. А **как** Вы считаете?

Comment: Считаю, что можно, хотя я бы так не сказал. Но нашёл в гугло-книгах пару удачных примеров с употреблением причастия "строимый", в которых альтернатива звучала бы хуже, наверное. Обратите внимание, что о его редком употреблении Пешковский говорит более 100 лет тому назад. Похоже, сейчас слово возвращается в русский язык (и мне это нравится, поскольку слово удобное).

Comment: Беспокоимый - тоже хорошее слово? Куда оно пропало? В Нацкорпусе четыре примера из 19 века. Не образуются причастия от переходных  глаголов клеить, сеять, веять. Можно предположить,  что суффиксы ИМ/ЕМ плохо согласуются с корневой гласной? Или что можно предположить?

Comment: Ой-ё, не филолог я, столько много мозгов у меня нет. Но вот здесь **о беспокоимом** (Еськова): https://books.google.ee/books?id=STRqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=aJCb4OS8Xw&sig=w8IdWHFb9tThMh7DMKcS1fAnqYc&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwilpJjIg7neAhVKBywKHe4pDYE4ChDoATAMegQIARAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9&f=false _Не беспокоимый никаким дуновением, спал и дуб._ А.  Феденко.

Comment: @Ксения  _Ум просит покою; он беспокоит сердце, сам беспокоимый всем: людьми, предметами, Богом, – нет, мало этого: беспокоимый самим собой._ С. Дурылин Согласна, беспокоимый - хорошее словечко (мне нравится).

Answer (score 2):

Правильно, разумеется, стро**и**мые (ср. стро**и**тся).

Словообразование вполне корректно, и вопрос может стоять только об области употребления слова. Оно может употребляться в неформальных случаях, когда "строящиеся" не подходит по смыслу (это слово тяготеет к значению "строящиеся *в данный момент*") или стилю. Например, если требуется подчеркнуть, *чьими силами* строятся эти самые дома, то выражение "строящиеся компанией Спецстрой" подходит для канцелярских отчётов, в то время как дома, "строимые" небезызвестным Джеком, могли бы отличаться особыми качествами, в силу вкладываемых им душевных сил и т. п. Попытка же некоторых толкователей объявить одно из слов "единственно правильным" мне представляется недальновидной, поскольку без необходимости обедняет язык.

Comment: >> *в то время как дома, "строимые" небезызвестным Джеком, могли бы отличаться особыми качествами, в силу вкладываемых им душевных сил и т. п*. Джек построил всего один дом.

Comment: @Alex_ander Строящиеся дома: здесь "строящийся" - это причастие, обозначает признак действия, совершаемого в настоящее время. Строимые дома: здесь "строимый" при отсутствии зависимого слова в Т.п. - это прилагательное, и что оно означает?  По крайней мере, оно не может обозначать признак как действие (по определению). Отглагольные прилагательные обозначают какое-то отношение к действию. Можно привести реальный пример и назвать это отношение?

Comment: убрал свой ответ - в пользу вашего. Тем не менее, обращаю внимание, что слово звучит неестественно, чаще говорят - строящиеся.